# Apple SSL Secure Transport

Tags: macos, ssl, secure-transport

I have just started to work with OS X and have no experience with it at all. But all I want to do now is to replace old OpenSSL code with Apple Security API. I'm using [Secure Transport](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/secure_transport) and I'm a bit confused about these functions: [`SSLSetIOFuncs`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1396081-sslsetiofuncs), `SSLWrite`, and `SSLRead`.

So `SSLSetIOFuncs` sets callbacks that perform writing/reading operations (which I should implement). And a lot of questions appear at this point:

1. First, I just don't understand why I should implement it (in OpenSSL it is implemented already). But ok, I just have to.
2. Should this implementation be encrypted? I guess no.

Also there are the following 2 functions:

```
OSStatus
SSLWrite                    (SSLContextRef      context,
                             const void *       __nullable data,
                             size_t             dataLength,
                             size_t             *processed);

OSStatus
SSLRead                    (SSLContextRef       context,
                            void *              data,           
                            size_t              dataLength,
                            size_t          *processed);
```

And they are "Normal application-level read/write." according to code comments. So why do I need to define those 2 callbacks for reading and writing then? And if the first two are callbacks which functions should I call for reading/writing in my code (when I really need to read some data from the server)?

There is no good documentation and I got stuck with it all. Maybe I'm just way too dumb but a little help would be just perfect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

SecureTransport is callback-based, unlike OpenSSL's `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` functions. This could require big changes to your code. If you want a `read`/`write`-style API that can use SecureTransport for encryption,  look at [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH1-DontLinkElementID_30) and specifically [CFStream](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfstream?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks! I see that you are familiar with this API. Could you please answer another question then? How correctly these 2 callbacks (SSLReadFunc and SSLWriteFunc) should be implemented then? If I implement just reading/writing from/to socket (for example using C posix read/write functions) what about encryption then (because OpenSSL SSL_write() and SSL_read() perform encryption)? And how SSLWrite, SSLRead functions and SSLReadFunc, SSLWriteFunc callbacks are connected? Should I call SSLWrite, SSLRead in these two callback functions?

Comment: SSLWrite() and SSLRead() should only be used when your SSL session is established. If you work with BSD Sockets then is recommend that you follow these examples : https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket  and https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher